# SQL Query to find max using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to solve this -
From the dataset given, write a SQL query to find the CustomerIDs of the customers who have placed the highest number of orders in the year 1996.

Here's what I have written but this doesn't seem to give correct answer -

```
select c.customerId
     , COUNT(*) 
  from orders o 
  JOIN customers c 
    ON o.customerId = c.customerId 
 WHERE YEAR(o.orderDate  ) = 1996 
 GROUP 
    BY c.customerId
```

[image]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, **chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.**

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. When pinned down this will be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: Are you using Postgres or MySQL?  They are not the same.

Comment: Incidentally, note that while `YEAR(o.orderDate  ) = 1996` cannot use an index, `o.orderdate BETWEEN '1996-01-01' AND '1997-01-01'` can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions with `group by`:

```
select customerid
from (select o.customerId, count(*),
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
      where o.orderDate >= '1996-01-01' and o.orderDate < '1997-01-01'
      group by o.customerId
    ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work (the logic below uses windows function) -

```
 Select t.customerId
 from
     (Select Tab.*,
            Rank() over(partition by customerId order by number_of_orders desc) as rank_orders
            from
             (select    c.customerId,
                     , COUNT(distinct order_id)  As number_of_orders
                       from 
                       orders as o 
                       INNER JOIN 
                       customers as c 
                       ON o.customerId = c.customerId 
                       WHERE YEAR(o.orderDate ) = 1996 
                       group by c.customerId) Tab) t
   where t.rank_orders = 1;
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error at `as rank_orders`

Comment: I am trying to run on mysql.

Comment: Can you tell me what the error message is?

Comment: Hmm, you can use windows function starting with MySQL 8 , which version are you using?